# How to detect scroll direction when content changes height on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, animation

It's quite straightforward to detect the scroll direction when scrolling page with static size. But if one of the elements is a sticky header and changes the height while scrolling it keeps changes `pageYOffset` and enters into infinite loop jumping up and down.

[Example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-water-d9irl?file=/src/App.js) where if you scroll to the point were it starts shrinking it starts jumping.

Some possible solution I've came up with was to add a spacer which would compensate when the sticky navigation gets smaller. But that requires doing it in the actual component. Wondering if there is a way to do it with js only in the `useScrollDirection` hook.

One of the other things I've tried was to use `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` and check for the size change, that didn't help as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion. I think you are underutilizing `position: sticky`. You don't need an event listener to achieve the behavior you want. You can do this entirely with CSS and let the browser handle everything for you.

```css
.app {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300vh;
}

.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: -120px;
  height: 150px;
  background: aquamarine
}

.nav_item {
   position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
  <nav class="nav">
    <p class="nav_item">Hello</p>
  </nav>
  <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @slumbergeist! I might trying utilizing this! 

but this example is rather simplified to the essence from the real app. In the real app there is a change in font height and few other things, which needs signalling from scroll.

Comment: Your solution is definitely great, just that I don't want to re-write every implementation with sticky sub navigation 

Comment: I've updated the example with font change.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and a co-worker recommended me to listen to the `wheel` event. So I implemented the following react hook:

```js
const useLastMouseWheelDirection = () => {
  const [lastMouseWheelDirection, setLastMouseWheelDirection] = useState(
    undefined
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (event) => {
      setLastMouseWheelDirection(event.deltaY >= 0 ? 'down' : 'up')
    }
    window.addEventListener('wheel', handler)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('wheel', handler)
  }, [])

  return lastMouseWheelDirection
}
```

This solution has some serious limitations:

- Obviously touch events are ignored
- Clicking and dragging the scroll bar will not fire the event

Also a side effect to the desired behavior would be that it wouldn't take into consideration if the element is even overflowing or not, although the hook could be extended to catch this case.

Further more the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) state:

> Note: Don't confuse the wheel event with the scroll event. The default action of a wheel event is implementation-specific, and doesn't necessarily dispatch a scroll event. Even when it does, the delta* values in the wheel event don't necessarily reflect the content's scrolling direction. Therefore, do not rely on the wheel event's delta* properties to get the scrolling direction. Instead, detect value changes of scrollLeft and scrollTop of the target in the scroll event.

So please take this answer with a grain of salt.